# Easier way to work with $$

Tags: php, variables

I am looking for an easier way to make my example below:

```
<?php
   $q = "Q".rand(1, 3);
   echo $$q;
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Easier" in what way? That is how you use variable variables.

Comment: Any time you're using variable variables, you should probably be using arrays instead.

Comment: perhaps use an array instead of Q1 Q2 Q3?

Comment: Looking to make it in only one line. :)

Comment: One line? Don't press enter after you've typed the first line then ;)

Comment: I expected this response Ben. Will make this with array. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   $array = array(1,2,3)
   $key = rand(1, 3);
   echo $array[$key];
?>
```